# Fetch FQL data with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

****UPDATE***
The data was being returned but not being output to the browser. When I looked at the source it was all there after I used the urlencode recommendation in the answer below.**

Pulling my hair out with this one.

Based on the following links:

[facebook FQL overview](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

and [FQL Video table info](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/)

This code should work to pull the table data I need:

```
ini_set("display_errors","2");
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);

$contents = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner= *******myID****');

echo $contents;
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT  vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner= ******myID*****) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /vservers/mywebsite/htdocs/test.php on line 5
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if you try this in a browser, are you getting results?

Comment: The error above is what is output in the browser.

Comment: I mean the url : https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner= *******myID****

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the main line to:

```
$enc = urlencode('SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner= *******myID****');
$contents = file_get_contents("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=$enc");
```

Comment: Now a different error: Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: SSL: fatal protocol error in /vservers/lingua/htdocs/test.php on line 6

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried facebook php sdk:

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    'query' => 'SELECT whatever FROM wherever WHERE something = something', 
    'method' => 'fql.query'));
```

oh, and take a look at this:

> You could try adding "limit 25" to the
>   end of the query, or if you need to
>   get as many status updates as
>   possible, you can go up to 500.  If a
>   query would return more than 500
>   records and there is no limit
>   explicitly stated in the query,
>   Facebook returns an empty result: no
>   errors, no nothing.

this probably isn't your error, but it's important to know

Comment: I looked over this document (of course now github is not coming up) the class requires a app key and secret key. This would involve creating an app. Do I need to create an app to pull the data I need?

Comment: tackled me there, I think it will work if you put in NULL for appid and appsecret....

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused because of **spaces** in URL request:

```
query=SELECT vid, owner
------------^----^-----
```

When **spaces** are changed to **%20** - it works. 
The most simple way is simply [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) your entire URL, or urlencode query only (*as suggested by [James C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98696/james-c), above*), and then, if needed, [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) your gotten $contents

```
ini_set("display_errors","2");
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);

$url = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner= *******myID****';
$contents = file_get_contents(str_replace(" ", "%20", $url));
$contents = stripslashes($contents);

echo $contents;

// FETCHING RESULTS IT IN TO ARRAY:
$array = json_decode($contents, true);
print_r($array);
```